# Android Limit Notifications To Every 5 Minutes

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app that sends push notifications through Google Cloud Messaging every time a message is sent between users.

If a user sends 3 messages in 3 seconds, the app obnoxiously delivers 3 notifications.

I set up a collapse key so they will just combine into 1 notification, but they still arrive at 3 separate times including vibration, etc.

I want to limit the notifications to once every 5 minutes, based on the collapse key.

So if I get 3 messages in the same minute with the 'message' collapse key, it would stop the 2 second messages from notifying the phone.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`collapse_key` would only work in the case you desctrbe if the recipient device was offline when you sent the three messages to GCM server. In that case, GCM server would store only the last message (discarding the first two), and deliver it when the device gets back online.

If they device is active, all the messages would be delivered to it, no matter if they have the same `collapse_key`.

In this case your options are :

1. Limit in your server the number of messages that device A can send to device B to once every 5 minutes. This would require you to implement logic in your server to store the date of the last message from each device A to each device B.
2. In the device, override the old notification with a new notification (by using the same notification ID when showing the notification), so that only one notification is displayed in the tray. However, in this case the device would still get all 3 messages.